# @ExceptionHandler doesn't catch MethodArgumentNotValidException

Tags: java, spring

I have the following `@ControllerAdvice`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingController {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { MethodArgumentNotValidException.class,
            EntityExistsException.class, BadCredentialsException.class, MismatchedInputException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> invalidInput(RuntimeException ex) {
        ExceptionResponse response = new ExceptionResponse();
        response.setErrorCode("BAD_REQUEST");
        response.setErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse>(response,
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

And the validator is bound to the controller this way:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/authentication")
public class UserAccountControllerImpl implements UserAccountController {

    @Autowired
    private UserAccountService userAccountService;

    @Override
    public UserAccountEntity login(@Valid @RequestBody UserAccountEntity account,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws BadCredentialsException {
        return userAccountService.authenticateUserAndSetResponsenHeader(
                account.getUsername(), account.getPassword(), response);
    }

    @Override
    public UserAccountEntity create(@Valid @RequestBody UserAccountEntity userAccount,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws EntityExistsException {
        String username = userAccount.getUsername();
        String password = userAccount.getPassword();
        userAccountService.saveIfNotExists(username, password);
        return userAccountService.authenticateUserAndSetResponsenHeader(
                username, password, response);
    }

    //used to bind the validator to the incoming request
    @InitBinder
    public void binder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(new UserAccountValidator());
    }
}
```

And this is the `UserAccountValidator` used to validate the incoming `UserAccountEntity`:

```
public class UserAccountValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return UserAccountEntity.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        UserAccountEntity userAccount = (UserAccountEntity) target;
        String password = userAccount.getPassword();
        String username = userAccount.getUsername();
        EmailValidator emailValidator = EmailValidator.getInstance();
        if (!emailValidator.isValid(username)) {
            errors.reject("Username must be a valid email address");
        }
        if (password.length() > 30 || password.length() < 8) {
            errors.reject("Password must be at least 8 and at most 30 characters");
        }
        if (!Pattern.compile( "[0-9]" ).matcher(password).find()) { // it doesn't contain any digit
            errors.reject("Password must have at least one digit");
        }
        if (password.toUpperCase().equals(password)) { //it's all upper-case
            errors.reject("Password must have at least one lower case character");
        }
        if (password.toLowerCase().equals(password)) { //it's all lower-case
            errors.reject("Password must have at least one upper case character");
        }
    }
}
```

When I pass in an invalid password/username, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 0 in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.myproject.project.core.controller.ExceptionResponse> com.myproject.project.core.controller.ExceptionHandlingController.invalidInput(java.lang.RuntimeException): No suitable resolver for argument 0 of type 'java.lang.RuntimeException'
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:175) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
```

Why doesn't it catch `MethodArgumentNotValidException`?

Comment: where are you actually throwing this exception?

Comment: I assume that it happens automatically: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/MethodArgumentNotValidException.html when @Valid fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least, an exception MethodArgumentNotValidException is not a RuntimeException, but you use RuntimeException argument in that exception handler.
For test change RuntimeException to Exception in method's argument.